# regex in sed to keep current line but remove next line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

This is sample data:

```
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
Plan CustomA
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
Plan CustomD
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
Plan CustomE
```

This is the regex works in `vscode`:

```
(Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}\n)(.*)
```

Expected output:

```
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
```

But I'm trying in `sed` with regexes like this but they don't work:

```
-E 's|(Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}\n)(.*)\n|\1|g'
-re 's|(Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}\n)(.*)\n|\1|g'
-zre 's|(Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}\n)(.*)\n|\1|g'
```

How can I do this? I think the issue is with `\n` because when I remove that, the sample works (but still it's not the expected output).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (checked with `GNU sed`, syntax might vary for other implementations):

```bash
$ sed -E '/Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}$/{n; d}' ip.txt
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
```

`n` command prints the pattern space (if auto-print is not disabled by `-n` option), replaces it with the next line and `d` will delete it.

Comment: @potong good catch! I've added the line anchor

Answer (score 2):

By default `sed` is line-based and you cannot process several lines at once like you are trying to do in your two first atempts. To apply your strategy you must, for instance, concatenate the next line to the current one (`N` command) and then process this block of two line:

```
sed -E '/Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}$/{N;s/\n.*//}'
```

Another solution, if you are using GNU `sed`, if your file is not too large and does not contain `NUL` bytes (ASCII code 0), is to use the `-z` option to slurp the whole file as one single line with embedded newline characters (with the `-z` option `sed` considers that the input lines are terminated by a `NUL` byte instead of a newline):

```
sed -Ez 's/(Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}\n)[^\n]*\n/\1/g'
```

This is almost what you tried with your 3rd attempt but as the `(.*)` group you used matches everything including newline characters you got only the first group printed... Replacing `(.*)` with `[^\n]*` in your 3rd attempt should work. Note also that as you want to suppress it there is no need for grouping.

With GNU `sed` you can also use the multi-line mode of the `s` command (`m` modifier) such that the period does not match a newline:

```
sed -Ez 's/(Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}\n).*\n/\1/gm'
```

As others also proposed `awk` solutions here is a simple one:

```
awk 's{s=0;next} /Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}$/{s=1} 1'
```

That is, if variable `s` is different from 0 (or the empty string) reset it to 0 and skip the current line (`next`). Else, if the current line matches your regex, set variable `s` to 1. Finally, print the current line (`1`).

Answer (score 2):

sed is usually not the best tool for anything that involves processing multiple input lines at a time.

Using any POSIX awk and only storing 1 line in memory at a time:

```
$ awk '!f; {f=(/^Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}$/)}' file
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```bash
$ awk '{where=match($0,"Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}"); if (where) {print; getline} else {print}}' file
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using `match` function of `awk` which uses regex in it to get the matched values.

```
awk -v RS="" '
{
  while(match($0,/Value[0-9]+ [0-9a-z]{8}\n[^\n]*/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    split(val,arr,ORS)
    prevLine=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    gsub(/^\n+|\n+$/,"",prevLine)
    print prevLine ORS arr[1]
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, all the professors have gathered here. Can I also suggest a way?

```
awk --posix '/Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}/ { print prev ORS $0 } { prev = $0 }' data.txt

#OR

awk --posix '/Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}/ { print prev; print $0 } { prev = $0 }' data.txt
```

output :

```
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
```

Comment: When the current line matches the regex this does not exactly _keep current line but remove next line_ (title of the question). Instead, it prints the previous and current lines. It works on the given example but it would not if, for instance, line `Plan CustomA` was repeated. All would be removed, not just the line following the match. This may be what the OP want, or it could be equivalent because there is always only one line between a _Value_ line and the next _Server_ line, but this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -v -f <(
     grep -P -A 1 "Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}" file |
     grep -P -v "Value[0-9]{1,2} [0-9a-z]{8}"
 ) file
ServerA
Value1 fh824rfz
ServerB
Value3 9fgjzxlo
ServerC
Value10 339fgh0l
```

Answer (score 0):

save up `$0` in `awk`, then use a dummy `getline` to "remove next line" by leveraging its return code as the `substr()`'s starting index, and using assignment to overwrite the "next line" with the current one :

```
jot 10 |
```

---

```
mawk '(__ = $_)~/[3-7]/ && $!NF = substr(__, getline)'
```

---

```
3
5
7
```